# Как взять переменную из другого класса?

Tags: c#, ооп, list

Идея была такая-можно купить стандартные букеты или собрать свой(сюда думаю прикрутить стратегию при выборе нужных букетов), цена одного цветка хранится в наследниках Flower, а общая цена за букет рассчитывается букете, тут-то и у меня проблема, я не смог вытащить значение цены цветка. Так же у меня тут не работающий мементо, в диктионари надо хранить(я так думаю) саил чек, но я что-то напутал с синтаксисом). В будущем планирую сделать ui и сохранять, чеки в базу или xml через сериализацию. Критику по архитектуре категорически приветствую)

```
namespace FlowerShop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bouquet[] bouquet = new Bouquet[3];
            //save state to sales check
            SaleHistory sale = new SaleHistory();

            bouquet[0] = new RosesStandard(2);
            bouquet[1] = new PetuniasStandard(4);
            bouquet[2] = new Custom(3);
            //display participants of bouguet
            foreach(Bouquet participants in bouquet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + bouquet.GetType().Name + "--"+
                    " Price:"+Flower.price);
                foreach (Flower flower in participants.Flowers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + flower.GetType().Name +
                        " Price:" + participants.Coast);
                    sale.History.Add(SId,participants.SaveState());
                }
            }

            //wait
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    abstract class Flower
    {
        public int price { get; set; }//think over
    }

    class Rose :Flower
    {
        public Rose()
        {
            price = 200;
        }
    }

    class Peony:Flower
    {
        public Peony()
        {
            price = 100;
        }
    }

    class Petunia :Flower
    {
        public Petunia()
        {
            price = 132;
        }
    }

    abstract class Bouquet
    {
        private List<Flower> _flowers = new List<Flower>();
        public int Coast { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Bouquet(int c)
        {
            Count = c;
            Coast = Flowers.price * c;

            this.CreateBouquet();
        }

        public List<Flower> Flowers
        {
            get { return _flowers; }
            private set { _flowers = Flowers; }
        }

        //save state
        public SalesCheck SaveState()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thx for bought. Spend: for Flower{0} Count{1} Pay{2}",Flowers, Count, Coast);
            return new SalesCheck(Coast, Count, Flowers);
        }

        //restore state - i don't think this need inherited
        public void RestoreState(SalesCheck memento)
        {
            this.Count = memento.Count;
            this.Coast = memento.Coast;
            this.Flowers = memento.Flowers2;
            Console.WriteLine("Was bougth: Flower{0} Count {1} Payed {2}",
                 Count, Coast, Flowers);
        }

        //Factory method
        public abstract void CreateBouquet();
    }

    class RosesStandard:Bouquet
    {
        public RosesStandard(int c) : base(c)
        { }
        public override void CreateBouquet()
        {
            Flowers.Add(new Rose());
        }
    }

    class PetuniasStandard:Bouquet
    {
        public PetuniasStandard(int c):base(c)
        { }
        public override void CreateBouquet()
        {
            Flowers.Add(new Petunia());
        }
    }

    class Custom : Bouquet
    {
        public Custom(int c):base(c)
        { }
        public override void CreateBouquet()
        {
            Flowers.Add(new Rose());
            Flowers.Add(new Peony());
        }
    }

    class SalesCheck
    {
        public int Count { get; private set; }
        public int Coast { get; private set; }
        //this need be abstract?=\
        //private int List<Flower> _flowers2= new List<Flower>();//think over
        public List<Flower> Flowers
        {
            get { return _flowers; }
            private set { _flowers = Flowers; }
        }

        private List<Flower> _flowers = new List<Flower>();

        public SalesCheck(int Count,int Coast,List<Flower> flowers)
        {
            this.Flowers = flowers;
            this.Coast = Coast;
            this.Count = Count;
        }
    }

    class SaleHistory
    {
        public int SId { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<int, SalesCheck> History = new Dictionary<SId, SalesCheck>();
        public SaleHistory()
        {
            History = new Dictionary<SId, SalesCheck>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробежав мельком, заметил следующие ошибки:

1. Вы обращаетесь к свойству `price`, как к статическому: обращение идет по имени класса, а не по имени экземпляра. Поэтому ошибка компиляции.

Т.е. получается:

```
Flower flower = new Rose();
Console.WriteLine(flower.price); // Вот так правильно
Console.WriteLine(Flower.price); // А это ошибка уровня компиляции: 
                                 // обращение как к статическому свойству.
```

2. Ошибка в свойстве `Flowers` в классе `Bouquet`, а именно в сеттере. У вас получается бесконечная рекурсия.

Нужно:

```
public List<Flower> Flowers {
    get { return _flowers; }
    private set { _flowers = value; }
}
```

Если C# 6, то можно сократить:

```
public List<Flower> Flowers { get; private set; } = new List<Flower>();
```

3. При создании словаря вы должны указать типы ключа и его значения.

Запись вида:

```
History = new Dictionary<SId, SalesCheck>();
```

Является совсем бредовой, т.к. вы пытаетесь вместо типа указать значение поля SId. Нужно:

```
History = new Dictionary<int, SalesCheck>(); // int - тип ключа
                                             // SalesCheck - тип значения
```

А работать уже с ним следующим образом:

```
 // Лучше работать через индексатор
 // Т.к. в этом варианте, если в словаре по ключу 0 будет уже значение, то
 // словарь бросит исключение.
 sale.History.Add(0, participants.SaveState());
 // Через индексатор. В этом случае он просто заменит старое значение на новое
 sale.History[0] = participants.SaveState();
```

### UPD

Чтобы посчитать цену букета, можно сделать так:

```
public Bouquet(int c) {
    Count = c;
    this.CreateBouquet();
    // Первый вариант, через LINQ
    Coast = Flowers.Sum(flower => flower.price);
    // Второй вариант, без LINQ
    Coast = 0;
    foreach(var flower in Flowers)
        Coast += flower.price;    
}
```

Кстати, у Вас методы `CreateBouquet` в производных классах, не учитывает количество цветов.
Также, для цен используйте тип [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/364x0z75.aspx), а не int.

#### Насчет архитектуры.

Если классы цветов (Rose, Peony и т.д.) отличаются лишь ценой, то я бы не стал их создавать, т.к. они избыточны. Я бы завел только неабстрактный класс Flower и метод, создающий нужные цветы. В этот метод я передывал бы строку с именем цветка, а он по переданному имени искал бы соответствующую цену и создавал цветок бы с такой ценой.
Т.е. что-то вроде этого:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> flowers = new Dictionary<string, decimal>() {
    ["rose"] = 200m,
    ["peony"] = 100m,
    ["petunia"] = 132m
};

Flower CreateFlower(string nameFlower) {
    decimal price;
    if(flowers.TryGetValue(nameFlower, out price))
        return new Flower() {
            price = price
        };
    return null;
}
```

Но если каждый цветок будет иметь свои какие-то доп. свойства или поведение, то тогда да, я бы разделил на классы.

Comment: Спасибо) 
Проглядел сетер и словарь)
А вот как выцепить значение из `flower` в `Bouquet` так и не догнал.
Попробовал:
`public List<Flower> _flowers = new List<Flower>();
        public List<Flower> Flowers
        {
            get { return _flowers; }
            private set { _flowers = value; }
        }
        public int Coast { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Bouquet(int c)
        {
            Count = c;
            Coast = Flowers.price * c;

            this.CreateBouquet();
        }`
Пишет не содержит такой переменной.

Comment: @Fel Цена букета - это сумма цен каждого цветка в этом букете. Т.е. нужно просуммировать цены всех цветов. Это и будет цена букета.

Comment: т.е. тупо в маине? а в букете не получится без строительства велосипеда? 
Хотя интересно как правильней)

Comment: @Fel, обновил ответ

Comment: Воу пример с линкью мне понравился)
А по поводу количества цветов это да(, но  я хочу доделать\переделать чтобы при создании экземпляра указывалось и цветы и их количество, хотя это для кастомного букета. Сдается мне надо будет переделать базовый класс.

Comment: Хм, в итоге отказываемся от листа в букете, вместо него пишем что-то вроде `Flower flowers = new Flower(); ` а в производных `flowers.CreateFlower("rose");` так? Это дает нам сильную связанность(?)

Comment: @Fel , производных классов нет. Есть только класс Flower, и в нем (а может быть и не в нем) статический метод, который создаёт объекты класса Flower с ценой, соответствующей переданной строке (имени цветка). Опять же нужно учитывать, что в дальнейшем нужно будет от системы. Может быть в дальнейшем Вы будете моделировать выращивание цветов. Тогда каждый цветок будет по-своему расти, иметь свою реализацию метода роста. Тогда классы для конкретных цветов нужны.

Comment: Я про классы типа букет, от них наверное не стоит отказываться, хотя можно было бы и их убрать, и создать один букет со всей логикой внутри, но это же вроде как плохо со стороны ооп. Хотя городить паттерны ради паттернов тоже "плохая практика" ). Я думаю дальнейшему развитию это не подлежит) А если захочу то у меня гит с кучей веток разных вариантов останется и из них сотворю нечто)